# Why do I get "can't find crate" that is listed as a dependency in Cargo.toml when I compile with rustc?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My Cargo.toml includes this:

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
```

And my code includes this:

```
extern crate chrono;
use chrono::{Duration, DateTime, Utc};
```

yet when I run my code, I get this error:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `chrono`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | extern crate chrono;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

I am working on an Exercism exercise, so the way I am building/running the program is `rustc src/lib.rs` to test my solution. Is the problem because I'm not running `rustc src/main.rs`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you're directly running `rustc`, all that compiler knows is the command line arguments. It doesn't know anything about `Cargo.toml`, in particular, and so it doesn't know where to look for `chrono` library.

To use dependency management, you have to compile your project with Cargo - just use `cargo build`/`cargo run`/`cargo test`, and everything should be fine. See [the Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html) for details.

If, however, you want (for some reason) use `rustc` directly, I'd advise to check first `cargo` anyway, by using `cargo build --verbose`. It will show all the commands that are invoked, allowing you to inspect the possible arguments to be defined manually.

Comment: See also [Can I install a library using Cargo without a Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36813893/155423)