# Why building with rustc command cannot see crates?

Tags: rust

Hi I'm trying to explore Rust. What I'm trying to do is using glob module, when i build code with $cargo build and $cargo run it's succesfully builds and runs the executable but if i try it with $rustc main.rs it gives me

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `glob`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use glob::glob;
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `glob`
```

Any ideas?

> Version :  ╰─ rustc --version rustc 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)

Code is here:

```
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    for entry in glob("/home/user/*.jpg").unwrap(){
        match entry {
            Ok(path) => println!("{:?}", path.display()),
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}",e),
        }

    };
}
```

My toml

```
[package]
name = "test1"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ieuD <example@mail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
glob = "0.3.0"
```

Comment: You do have to tell rustc where to find the external crate (that you've already built) and also the library path where the dependencies of that crate can be found. What is your rustc command line?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen my command was straight rustc src/main.rs. 
for clarification i've added glob dependency to toml file. [glob crate](https://crates.io/crates/glob)
and built with cargo. 
how can i specify the crate path. would you give me an example ?

Comment: You added a dependency to **Cargo**.toml file, a configuration file for **Cargo**... If you want to see an example of working rustc calls, run "cargo clean && cargo -v build" to see the commands cargo runs. https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc lists the command line options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rustc` on its own doesn't handle your dependencies, it just compiles stuff. When you run `rustc` on your file, it will start compiling it and encounter the unknown `glob` crate. Dependencies are [handled by `cargo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) via `Cargo.toml`.

Though you could only use `rustc` (see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813893/can-i-install-a-library-using-cargo-without-a-cargo-toml)) it's a task that's considerably more difficult, that's why `cargo` is around.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. and sorry for possible duplicate question :))