# How can I avoid rebuilding dependencies when `cargo install` fails due to a system configuration issue?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to `cargo install` a project with many dependencies. One of the later dependencies fails to build due to some system configuration issue:

```
cargo install diesel_cli
   ... many dependencies here...
   Compiling diesel_cli v1.4.1
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: ...large output removed...
  = note: ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Once I think I've solved the system configuration issue, I need to re-run `cargo install`, wait a while for the first set of dependencies to build, then see if I get past the failure.

How can I avoid rebuilding all of those dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message contains the directory containing the failed build artifacts:

```
error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v1.4.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/_b/d4_bd15x7s5g99cjvyhpw26w0000gp/T/cargo-installDQOdPD`
```

You can pass that directory via the `--target-dir` option (or setting the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` environment variable) to use it again, avoiding rebuilding the dependencies:

```
cargo install diesel_cli --target-dir=/var/folders/_b/d4_bd15x7s5g99cjvyhpw26w0000gp/T/cargo-installDQOdPD
```